# AS3 AIR: Smooth scrolling for mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

So, I'm building fairly simple application for portrait mode only, and it will have vertical scrolling for content.

Content is basicly a MovieClip containing image as background and other minor elements (couple small MovieClips as buttons etc).

The problem is that I don't seem to find a smooth way to scroll my content. I would love it to be smooth and accurate, and I've tried numerous different ways for it.

For testing purposes the background I'm using (inside my `content` MovieClip) is 533x1250 jpg from library.

This is how I add my `content` mc and backround into it:

```
scaleXFactor = stage.stageWidth / 640; //my stage is 640x960
...
addChild(content); //which is new MovieClip()
var bg:bg1 = new bg1();
bg.x = p1bg.y = 0;
bg.width = 640 * scaleXFactor; 
bg.scaleY = bg.scaleX;
content.width = bg.width;
content.height = bg.height;
content.addChild(bg);
```

For scrolling I assumed I'd be safe by just simply using MOUSE_DOWN & MOUSE_UP event listeners and basic ENTER_FRAME function like this:

```
mouseLastPos = stage.mouseY;
if(MouseUpVar == 1){                                                        
    mousePosDiff = (mouseOriPosY-mouseLastPos);         
}                                                       

content.y -= mousePosDiff*1.2;
mouseOriPosY = stage.mouseY;                            

if(MouseUpVar == 0){ //Smoothening which is allowed by MOUSE_UP
    if(mousePosDiff > 0){
        mousePosDiff -= 0.001;
    }else if(mousePosDiff < 0){
        mousePosDiff += 0.001;
    }
}
if(content.y < (content.height - stage.stageHeight)*-1){                
    content.y = (content.height - stage.stageHeight)*-1;
}else if(content.y > 0){
    content.y = 0;
}
```

In debug player it's as smooth as you can ever imagine, but in real device (Samsung Note4) it's very laggy and clumsy.

I've also tried freshplanet's script, which is not as laggy, but still a little clumsy, and messes up my scaleY for some reason.
  And IScrollerComponent seems to have some issues on AIR, and I didn't get any visual elements on my screen with it.
Rendering settings or cacheAsBitmap didn't seem to have any effect on this.

How should this be done right? Is it normal that this 'small' image (533x1250) causes bad lag? 
I really need to use AS3 and AIR for this, so I'm hoping to find a good and "simple" solution (yeah, that doesn't happen too often).

Thanks,
  kaarto

Comment: There's no such thing as a small movieclip on mobile devices. A movie can be 10x10 px and by itself drag the CPU to the ground due to numerous vector drawings. First test with only one raster background. Most mobile device can handle smoothly that scrolling,

Comment: @BotMaster thanks, noted. Simple raster seems to scroll a lot better, and it goes laggy after I add my bg and other nested movieclips. Any hints how I should proceed, or which framework & language to jump in (in order to create app like this fast, while having mostly only AS3 experience)? I'm targeting both, iOS and Android.

Comment: Are you using GPU acceleration?  So long as you avoid vector graphics and have your rendering mode set to GPU acceleration, it should be decent.   What's your framerate?  Also, "not smooth" can mean different things different people,  do you mean that the framerate seems to drop while scrolling?

Comment: With gpu mode you can have a lot of content and smooth scrolling in most devices as long as no vector graphics are involved. My own list engine runs great on all situation but I have extensive graphic management and renderer pooling implemented. Short answer yes you can have smooth list scrolling on mobile devices using AIR as long as everything is correctly implemented.

Comment: @BotMaster & BadFeelingAboutThis thank you guys again! Once again the main solution was pretty embarassing; now when using only bitmaps and GPU acceleration, it works like a charm! Using also scrollRect as Aaron suggested, but GPU+avoiding vectors gave the biggest boost here, so if you care to form an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cacheAsBitmap=true` on your content and `scrollRect` instead of moving your content.

Comment: This actually does make a little difference, thanks! But still little annoying lag happening when scrolling faster than ~2mm/sec.

Comment: Are there animations inside the content while scrolling?